# Cordova erro ao executar chamada Ajax

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5, apache-cordova, rest, cordova-plugin

Tenho uma aplicação Cordova 7.0.1 que faz uma requisição a um método de um site Asp.Net MVC Web API 4.6.
Quando a chamada é feita no dispositivo, *cordova run andoid*, a execução do método retorna erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se executo a chamada direto do browser, através de uma página HTML ou executar o App com *run cordova browser*, funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O método do controller *CategoriaApiController.cs* é este:

```
   public class CategoriaApiController : ApiController
{
    private DBContext db = new DBContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public string ListaCategorias(Categoria categoria)
    {
        var listaCategorias = (dynamic)null;
        try
        {
            listaCategorias = db.Categoria.OrderBy(x => x.Descricao).ToList();

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaCategorias);
            //return "user-error";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaCategorias);
            //return "user-error";
        }
    }

}
```

A classe *WebApiConfig.cs*:

```
   public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            EnableCrossSiteRequests(config);

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "AppLogin",
                routeTemplate: "api/login/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );

        }

        private static void EnableCrossSiteRequests(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
                origins: "*",
                headers: "*",
                methods: "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
        }
    }
```

E chamada ajax:

```
    function chamaListaCategorias(){
    // var categoria = new CategoriaController();
    // categoria.ListaCategorias();

  var url = BASE_URL + "api/CategoriaApi/ListaCategorias";

        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            $("#res").html("Local success callback.<br>") ;
            $("#res").html(data);

          },
          error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
            $("#res").html("Local error callback." + err + ' --- ' + status  + ' ---' + jqXHR);
            console.log(err);
          }


}
```

Instalei o plugin whitelist que no meu entendimento era para configurar este tipo de acesso.

Tem alguma configuração no App ou no Site para permitir que esta requisição funcione?

Answer (score 0):

O problema era em uma regra do firewall que estava bloqueando os pacotes do servidor.

Acertado as regras do firewall funcionou.